# How to make an op-amp to get close to ideal case

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am having trouble with LM324 type op-amp during my LTSpice simulations. When I used ideal op-amp, there is no problem and the circuit (Sallen-Key LPF) works perfectly. However, when I changed the op-amp to LM324, everything blew up and 0 dB response dropped down to -120 decibel in AC analysis at the same frequency range I was working with previously. I tried everything to make it close to ideal (like adding big resistors to input terminals / output terminal etc.). I have no choice but LM324 as this op-amp is the only one available in the lab of my school. This is what it looks like. What can I do?

[image: first pic]

[image: second working design]

Comment: You have to understand supply voltage ranges and common-mode input voltage ranges and even your LM324 will be much more ideal. These things are listed in the *datasheet*.

Comment: Looking at the circuit, what defines the DC biasing voltage at the + input of your opamp? Note that if you power an opamp with +3 V and 0 V (GND) that you might be unable to use the opamp's inputs close to those voltages. In most designs the opamp's inputs will be DC biased at a voltage "in the middle" of the supply so with +3 V and 0 V that would be +1.5 V.

Comment: Is there a reason you used a circuit that requires dual supplies but used a single supply? Is there a reason why the input has no DC biasing to known potential? Is there a reason you need to use 3V supply, as the input and output will at most have a range from 0V to 1.5V?

Comment: The LM324 is an really simple OPV without rail to rail output and an not negligible offset. Maybe this helps: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/5watnl/what_is_the_difference_between_ideal_opamp_and/

Comment: Is that 1M resistor in series with the opamp's output intentional?

Comment: @brhans   yes it is

Comment: @Justme sir the instructor told us to use 1 supply voltage. I do not understand that you said the input has no DC biasing to know potential. How can I achieve that? There is no reason I have to your questions. I am not very good at OP AMPs

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie sir do I have to add a DC supply next to sine voltage you mean?

Comment: I believe I made it. We are building a circuit which uses a microphone and I think when we talked to it, converted electrical signal will have enough dc offset and everything will be fine

Comment: Always have a look at the transient response of your op-amp output before attempting an AC analysis. Otherwise you run the risk of getting garbage from the implicit assumption of linearity.

Comment: LM324 is an antique op-amp. As mentioned, if the supply rails are only 3V apart, you'll get terrible performance. Use a modern opamp with 'rail to rail' inputs and outputs or a much wider voltage range. Like +-6V or so. You may be assuming your single power supply has to be connected to GND. It does not. You can use a 12V supply (for example), and easily achieve +6 and -6V for the op-amp power rails.

Comment: LM324 is a good general-purpose OPA. I did not read the detail, but it sounds like you want higher GBW OPA.